# Error while deploying Spring boot ( Version - 2.7.3 in wildfly ( version 10.0.0 ) || Java version 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment, wildfly

I am facing this problem from past 7 days. It would be really helpful if anyone can help me.

steps I follow:-

- 1st created a simple spring boot app using start.spring.io
- 2nd created a rest controller
- 3rd installed wildlfly software and created a user and stated the management console
- 4th created a war file using mvn clean install ( which also deploy in the wildfly console )

here is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>warehouse_connection</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>warehouse_connection</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <deploy.wildfly.host>127.0.0.1</deploy.wildfly.host>
    <deploy.wildfly.port>9990</deploy.wildfly.port>
    <deploy.wildfly.username>USERNAME</deploy.wildfly.username>
    <deploy.wildfly.password>PASSWORD</deploy.wildfly.password>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                <hostname>${deploy.wildfly.host}</hostname>
                <port>${deploy.wildfly.port}</port>
                <username>${deploy.wildfly.username}</username>
                <password>${deploy.wildfly.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the error I am getting when I use mvn clean install to crate war file and deploy in wildfly.

[Errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjUON.png)

Comment: The issue is in your formContentFilter bean. it seems to use jackson somehow but I think the versions don't match.

Comment: And the error is???

Comment: please press the error image

Comment: Wildfly 10 is over 6 years old. Can you use a more up-to-date version?

Comment: I cant actually its an requirement

Comment: I just solved this problem I will update the ques

Comment: Could you write your solution as an answer, please? And leave the question as a question.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit that edited a solution into your question. If you managed to solve your own problem, then please post an **answer** with that solution, and accept it after the time out. Do not add solutions to the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will write a answer and sorry for causing a confusion.